# Showing page from different domain for certain url?

Tags: .htaccess, dns, nameservers

I have a page on my site, mysite.com/test, that I want to load a page on another site, test.jit.su, for example. I had set up my nameservers with my registrar (godaddy) so that I could add an A record for mysite.com/test that would point to test.jit.su. This has posed a few problems with email and other things on my webhost, so I'm going to change the nameservers to those of the webhost.

Is there still a way to do this without the A records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS records can only set an alias on a domain (of any level), e.g. mydomain.com --> yotherdomain.com 
which also automatically implies redirects like 
mydomain.com/anything --> myotherdomain.com/anything 
but you can not do mydomain.com to one server and mydomain.com/anything to another server, if you want to do this you'll have to use HTTP redirect

Answer (score 0):

Changing A record will not resolve your issue as noted by @unleashed-dev.

You will need to **enable** `mod_proxy` in your Apache config for that. Once mod_proxy is enabled, enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# proxy /test to http://test.jit.su/test
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(test)/?$ http://test.jit.su/$1 [L,P,NC]
```